# Can't simulate XSS injection using PHP

Tags: php, xss, code-injection

I am testing injecting code into user inputted fields with the goal of preventing XSS.

OK - UPDATE: I've written the code below that is reproducible. I enter the following injection and the text field redirects but the textarea one does not. I can also see that on my original form it doesn't redirect due to some of the additional attributes which followed the echo (e.g. size="100px"). But in essence it shows the vulnerability. Why not with the textarea field?

Input into fields:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.location = 'http://www.example.com/'
</script>'";
```

Code:

```
<?
$descr='';
$title='';
if (isset($_POST['descr'])){
    $descr = $_POST['descr'];
}
if (isset($_POST['title'])){
    $title = $_POST['title'];
}
?>
<form method=post action=<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?> enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    Title: <input  type="text" name='title'><? echo $title ?></input>
    Description: <textarea name='descr'><? echo $descr ?></textarea>
    <input type=submit name='save' value='Save Post'>
</form>
```

Comment: What's preventing? You! If it is your script then you should exactly know what sanitization you have used.

Comment: You are correct. I oversimplified the original code.I was able to get redirection on a text field (not a textarea field).

Comment: `<input>` is a content-less element. If you want to set its value, use the `value` property

Answer (score 1):

Nothing obvious by looking at that particular bit of code out of context. We have no idea what $title or $descr are assigned here. For all we know the variables are initialized using [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip-tags) or [htmlentities](http://php.net/htmlentities).

For example to me, that output looks like it was run through strip_tags.

```
$title = strip_tags($_POST['title'])

<input type=text name='title' value= '<? echo $title ?>'" >
```

Comment: I can see my code could have been clearer: I have edited it above - no strip_tags or any protection.

Comment: Are you saying you are the one that wrote this code? Because this can't be reproduced as it stands.

Comment: Your code still makes no sense. You've either simplified the problem way too much (to the point where you removed the part that reproduces the problem) ... or you are doing something else that you aren't telling us about.

Comment: You are correct. I oversimplified the original code. I was able to get redirection on a text field (not a textarea field). See above - I've altered the original post with your encouragement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't show out user input in input field or textarea, browser doesn't allow to run from that place. Try next:

```
<div>
<? echo $descr ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't matter what I throw into the text fields. They just display exactly as typed.

Comment: Try next: <script>alert(1)</script>

Comment: One question: did browser change '<' to '&lt;'?

Comment: <script>alert(1)</script> displays the message on text fields, not textarea ones. Thanks for the suggestion.